# Issue with One to One Accounts and Converting Leads

Tags: apex, trigger, person-accounts, nonprofit-starter-pack

I'm currently working on a system that has the Nonprofit Starter Pack with One-to-One Accounts enabled. I have made a trigger that changes the default account of a contact to some account that has already been created in the system. In most cases, upon creation of the contact without a default account, the code in the Nonprofit Starter Pack will create a "Person Account", and I am able to use the System field `npe01__SYSTEMIsIndividual__c` to know that it is okay to give it a default account.

The issue I'm having is with Converting a Lead. When I convert a Lead, it automatically creates a Contact and also automatically creates a Person Account for that Contact. In my trigger, the `npe01__SYSTEMIsIndividual__c` is always false. I've tried to setup the trigger such that it fires before and after insert, but that field is always false. Then after all triggers have completed I always end up with a Person Account for that contact.

```
trigger SetDefaultAccountIndividualTrigger on Contact (after insert, before update) {
Map<ID, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosById();
List<Id> contactIds = new List<Id>();
Account individualAccount = null;
for(Contact contact : Trigger.new)
{
    RecordTypeInfo rt = rtMap.get(contact.RecordTypeId);
    System.debug(rt.Name);
    System.debug(contact.Id);
    if(rt.Name == 'General Contacts')
    {
        if(individualAccount == null)
        {
            individualAccount = [select Id,Name from Account where Name='Individual'];
        }

        if(contact.AccountId != null)
        {
            // Check if Contact's account is a Person Account'
            Account a = [select Id,npe01__SYSTEMIsIndividual__c,npe01__One2OneContact__c,npe01__SYSTEM_AccountType__c from Account where Id =: contact.AccountId];

            System.debug(contact.AccountId);
            System.debug(contact.Id);


            System.debug(a.npe01__SYSTEM_AccountType__c);
            System.debug(a.npe01__SYSTEMIsIndividual__c);
            System.debug(a.npe01__One2OneContact__c);

            if(!a.npe01__SYSTEMIsIndividual__c)
            {
                // If not a person account than move onto next Contact
                continue;
            }
        }
        contactIds.add(contact.Id);
    }
}
if(Trigger.isAfter)
{
    List<Contact> queriedContacts = [select Id,AccountId from Contact where Id in :contactIds];
    for(Contact c : queriedContacts){
        c.AccountId = individualAccount.Id;
    }
    update queriedContacts;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: Posted the code. Hope that helps.

Comment: What are you trying to do, what are the business rules here?

Comment: If the Contact has a record type of 'General Contacts' and had no Account specified we want to mark that Contact as an 'Individual' account by settings it Account equal to a static account named 'Individual' that we have already setup in the system. We do not want to use the installed One to One Accounts packaged and also we don't have the ability to remove that.